# Show font-awesome icon if image does not exist

Tags: angular

I'm working on an Angular2 project and I'm trying to show an svg icon stored inside my "menu" model. If this image does not exists, I want to to show a default icon from font-awesome. So I tried:

```
<img [src]="'../icons/' + menu.icon + '.svg'" (error)="fa-icon" />
<fa-icon #fa-icon class="icon-menu" icon="home"></fa-icon>
```

This is not working. The page is trying to load the stored svg icon and after that is showing the home icon. I want it to display one or another, not both.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I got it by doing this:

```
<img #customIcon [src]="'../icons/' + menu.icon + '.svg'" (error)="customIcon.hide= true" [hidden]="customIcon.hide" />
<fa-icon [hidden]="!customIcon.hide" class="icon-menu" icon="{{menu.icon}}"></fa-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img [hidden]="isError" (load)="this.imageIsLoaded = true;" (error)="this.isError = true;" [attr.src]="src" />

<span *ngIf="isError" class="fa-stack fa-3x">
    <i class="fas fa-map fa-stack-1x"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-ban fa-stack-2x" style="color:Tomato"></i>
</span>
```

I have done it like above and its working great in my solution. Hope it helps.